# Gradle doesn't build if sources jar is present

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I'm using a jar in my Android Studio project, `secretshare-1.4.1.jar`. Now, I also want to be able to see the source code of this, so I added `secretshare-1.4.1-sources.jar` to the libs forlder without adding it to the dependancies of the project. This allows me to browse the classes of the library along with their source.

But, the problem is that I can't build the project if I do that. The issue seems that the two jars have the same classes, so gradle gives a duplicate file error. But the sources jar isn't even present in the `build.gradle` file.

Here is a sample code that I'm trying to run :

```
import com.tiemens.secretshare.main.cli.MainSplit;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
...

public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "test message";
        String k = "1";
        String n = "2";
        String[] splitArgs = {"-n", n, "-k", k, "-sS", s};
        MainSplit.SplitInput splitInput = MainSplit.SplitInput.parse(splitArgs);
        MainSplit.SplitOutput splitOutput = splitInput.output();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
        splitOutput.print(ps);
        String content = baos.toString(); // e.g. ISO-8859-1
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sakhuja.ayush.secretsafe"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/secretshare-1.4.1.jar')
}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
Error:Gradle: duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\z\Academics\Code\SecretSafe\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK html/SecretShareApplet.html
    File 1: D:\z\Academics\Code\SecretSafe\app\libs\secretshare-1.4.1.jar
    File 2: D:\z\Academics\Code\SecretSafe\app\libs\secretshare-1.4.1.jar
```

And the error just goes away if I delete `secretshare-1.4.1-sources.jar` from the libs folder. But I really want to keep it as I want to refer to the library's source code. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

is going to grab every jar in the libs dir, including the secretshare-1.4.1-sources.jar. This also makes the 4 ending lines in your configuration block unnecessary. Exclude the secretshare-1.4.1-sources.jar specifically from the file tree:

```
    fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs', excludes: ['secretshare-1.4.1-sources.jar'])
```

I'd also recommend removing the final 4 lines from the config block, but that's just a suggestion and not strictly the question.